# Find a card based on index

Tags: java, enums

I have 3 fields and I'm using the enums Rank and Suit to represent the rank and suit of my card class. I also have a cardIndex field which is supposed to represent the the index of the card in a deck of 52. I am able to define a card class using the enums but I was wondering if there's a way to get the rank and suit of a card when given only the card index? As I wanted to create a constructor that just took a card index and then set the rank and suit from there..

```
private final Suit suit;
private final Rank rank;
private final int cardIndex;

public Card(int cardIndex)
{

}
```

Comment: But won't this leads to __DECK__ having the same sequence of cards  on every run!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 suits/13 ranks i guess. This here would work, if the cardindices counted up the ranks first and then the suits (index = 13 is the highest rank of suit 1). This way you can retrieve the suitindex/rankindex from the cardindex. The conversion to rank/suit is up to you.

```
public Suit getSuit(int cardIndex){
     int suitNo = cardIndex/13;

     return matchingSuit(suitNo);
}

public Rank getRank(int cardIndex){
     int rankNo = cardIndex % 13;

     return matchingRank(rankNo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
private final String suit;
private final int rank;
private final int cardIndex;

public Card(int cardIndex)
{
  if(cardIndex>13){
     int a = cardIndex/13;
     int b = (a*13)-cardIndex;
     suit = getSuit(a);
     rank = b;
  }else{
     suit = getSuit(0);
     rank = cardIndex;
  }
}

public String getSuit(int s)
{
   String suit;
   switch(s){
      case 1:
         suit = "Spade";
      break;

      case 2:
         suit = "Heart";
      break;

      case 3:
         suit = "Club";
      break;

      case 4:
         suit = "Diamond";
      break;

      return suit;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the card index is between 0 and 51, (or 1 and 52, depending on how you want to do it), then you could just have 0-12 represent spades, 13-25 represent diamonds, etc. Then just modulo the index to get the rank, and divide by 13 to get the suit of the card.

If you have a final array with all of the ranks (2-Ace) and suits(0-3), then you could just do a look up to get the matching ranks and suits from the index given

```
final int[] ranks = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}; //2-Ace
final int[] suits = {0,1,2,3}; //spades-hearts
private int rank;
private int suit;

public Card(int index) {
    rank = ranks[index % 13];
    suit = suits[index / 13];
}
```